# Active Directory not returning groups for all users

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've built a node.js app with express and the passport-azure-ad library in order to authenticate users via AAD. I want to get groups back in the auth callback for users that are logging in so I can ensure they belong to the correct security group before granting them access to parts of my app.

I edited my manifest for my Active Directory App (Clarity) to include

**"groupMembershipClaims": "All"**

This is working very well for all users that I have had log in except for one. Typically I get a response in the profile object of this form:

```
accessToken: "scrubbedAccessToken"
aio: "scrubbedAio"
amr: "["pwd"]"
family_name: "My Last Name"
given_name: "My First Name"
groups: Array[1]
    0: "[...hugeListofGuids...]"
    length: 1
in_corp: "true"
ipaddr: "my ip"
name: "My Name"
oid: "scrubbedOid"
onprem_sid: "scrubbedSid"
sub: "scrubbedSub"
tid: "scrubbedTid"
unique_name: "myemail@microsoft.com"
upn: "myemail@microsoft.com"
ver: "1.0"
```

But for some reason for one of my users my app gets this instead:

```
_claim_names: "{"groups":"src1"}"
_claim_sources: "{"src1":{"endpoint":"https://graph.windows.net/scrubbedTid/users/scrubbedOid/getMemberObjects"}}"
accessToken: "scrubbedAccessToken"
aio: "scrubbedAio"
amr: "["pwd"]"
family_name: "scrubbedLastName"
given_name: "scrubbedFirstName"
in_corp: "true"
ipaddr: "scrubbedIp"
name: "scrubbedFulleName"
oid: "scrubbedOid"
onprem_sid: "scrubbedSid"
sub: "scrubbedSub"
tid: "scrubbedTid"
unique_name: "scrubbedEmail"
upn: "scrubbedEmail"
ver: "1.0"
```

Can anyone give me some insight as to why I'd get different formats for different users? These users are both in the same tenant and their emails are in the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of Group Membership Claims that are returned in the Access Token are limited based on the token type.

Take a look at this blog post: [Azure Active Directory, now with Group Claims and Application Roles!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/)

> To ensure that the token size doesn’t exceed HTTP header size limits,
>   Azure AD limits the number of objectIds that it includes in the groups
>   claim. If a user is member of more groups than the overage limit (150
>   for SAML tokens, 200 for JWT tokens), then Azure AD does not emit the
>   groups claim in the token. Instead, it includes an overage claim in
>   the token that indicates to the application to query the Graph API to
>   retrieve the user’s group membership.

You are noticing a behavior which implies that this user is a member of too many groups, and you will need to call the AAD Graph API to get those details.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I've been trying to call the AAD Graph API to get group information for folks in this situation, but I'm having some trouble. I've been trying to call the url from my overage claims source

https://graph.windows.net/.../users/.../getMemberObjects?api-version=1.5 using the token I received witht he claims source as the bearer authorization, but I get Authentication_MissingOrMalformed. I've also tried using the nodejs passport-azure-ad authentication method to get a token for resourceURL: 'https://graph.windows.net', but that token also seems to be incorrect. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to make sure your application is configured to be able to get this data. Just like any other API in AAD, you need to request permissions to the Graph API, and then a user must consent to those permissions before the token will work. You must use a token specific for the AAD Graph API, with the resource claim 'https://graph.windows.net/'